# Select Hidden Faces / Vertices Problem

Tags: mesh

I am a beginner in Blender and I have the problem to select in edit mode all faces of a cube for e.g.

I duplicated the cube and I joined it. I am trying to learn join and unjoin. But the problem is, that there is always a rest of the hidden faces of the cube, if I move the unjoined cube. I hope I did explain it well.

I have heard, that there is a possibility to select all faces of a mesh, but I do not know anymore where I have heard it in which video. Could someone please help? Thank you very much! Have a great day!

Martina

Comment: So the question itself is ok, but it would be helpful if you provide images. Other than that you are probably looking for Ctrl+L.

Comment: Or just L. With Ctrl+L you automatically select everything connected to an existing selection. With L you can select everything connected to where your mouse is hovering over while pressing L without having to select anything beforehand. Or are you looking for the X-Ray option?